# how to load the py plugin in DolphinDB

Tags: linux, plugins, dolphindb

reported error message when i load the py plugin in DolphinDB,
here is my code below:

```
loadPlugin("/home/jwu/DolphinDB/DolphinDB_Linux64_V1.30.3/server/plugins/py/PluginPy.txt");
```

and error message here:

```
Couldn't load the dynamic library [plugins/py/libPluginPy.so]: ./libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by plugins/py/libPluginPy.so)
```

why

Comment: please add what you were trying to do and provide minimum reproduceable code

Answer (score 0):

This is because the glibc version of the Linux system is too low, but the plug-in is compiled with a higher version of glibc. So you need to upgrade the glibc.